# change color of full Modal

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, react-native, react-native-modal

I'm using a react native modal. I am trying to use a backgroundColor to fill the whole modal. However, the color is only applied to the top. Why is this so?

How can I fix this and apply the color to the whole modal view?

```
return (
    <Modal visible={isUserVisible}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* <View> */}
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.cross}
            onPress={() => setIsUserVisible(false)}>
            <Thumbnail
              source={{
                uri:
                  'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/very-basic-android-l-lollipop-icon-pack/24/close-512.png',
              }}></Thumbnail>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text>HELLOO</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.searchLocationContainer}>
          <UserInfoContainer
            firstName={firstName}</UserInfoContainer>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
```

```
export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#323443',
    //backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  button: {
    paddingTop: 0,
  },
  text: {
    color: 'black',
  },
  cross: {
    paddingTop: 50,
    paddingLeft: 40,
  },
  searchLocationContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `flex: 1` to the container style